# IdentityServer Resource Owner flow for specific IP

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer 4 and I wish to allow Resource Owner flow but only for a client with a specific IP address. How can I configure it?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` into your resource owner validator. This will give you access to the HTTP request.

This way you can check the IP address.